# Ссылка на маркер HTML

Tags: html, css

У меня есть код в файл.css ↓

```
#glheader {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(2562.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    background-size: 120px;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    background-position-y: 2px;
    background-position: 20px;
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Это код который позволяет поставить вместо маркера картинку, и у меня получилось некое меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код меню в `index.html`

```
<header>
  <element id="menu">
    <ul class="content">
      <div id="glheader">
        <li><a href="informacja.html">Informacja</a></li>
        <li><a href="strony.html">
            <font color="white">Moje strony</font>
          </a></li>
        <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </element>
</header>
```

И я теперь не могу понять, как мне сделать ссылку (`href="index.html"`) к этому маркеру, то есть это же тоже будто элемент меню, по которому когда я кликаю то меня должно перекидать на `index.html`
И я не понимаю где и как эту ссылку мне указать, указывал в `<div>` и не работает, а в файле со стилями не совсем понимаю как это сделать

Comment: А что мешает обернуть ваш элемент ссылкой?

Comment: Это маркер, не понимаю куда эту ссылку приписать

Comment: @Влад, залейте код на CodePen и дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку в комментарии (залейте только индексный файл и css, другого не надо). Так будет гораздо легче.

Comment: Не используйте тэг <font>: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font